# url open read is hanging up when I perform the read

Tags: python-3.x

urlopen(req).read() hanging up when I perform the read; I am using python3

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/los-angeles-ca/90012/weather-forecast/347625", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
print(webpage)
```

Any guidance will be appreciated